# Log4j2 Java unable to import org.apache.logging.log4j.core

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

I am trying to use the Log4j2 API to write a Converter plugin with version 2.8.2 but am unable to import `org.apache.logging.log4j.core` to import the following:

`org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent`, `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin`, `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.*`

I have added the maven dependencies as and this works fine with Log4j 2.8.1

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update: log4j-core-2.8.2.jar content**

[image]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.andrew_flower.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>logtest1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Release Distribution Repository</name>
            <url>
                http://repository.apache.org/snapshots
            </url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: So when you change version to 2.8.1 in maven pom, its get imported ?

Comment: @yvoytovych yes it gets imported with 2.8.1. core is not there in 2.8.2

Comment: I tried to create empty maven project, and add your posted chunk of pom config with version 2.8.2. It gets imported and all java imports works fine.
Maybe your IDE does not update maven dependencies, reimport Maven Project.

Comment: Please refer the updated question. This is the jar I get for 2.8.2

Comment: Could you please post a complete pom.xml

Comment: Posted the pom.xml

Comment: Are you seeing this jar in `.m2` directory?

Comment: Path could be `org/apache/logging/log4j` inside `.m2/repository` or `.m2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you experiencing weird configuration problems with maven local repository, because your log4j-core.jar content is from log4j-api.jar

I copied your pom.xml to my environment just for test, it works fine.
[image: my config]
Try navigate to log4j folder on your pc under .m2 repository *(yourUser/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j)* 
and delete all folders, then go to you project and execute **mvn install** to import all libraries one more time, i hope it will help.